# How many ways to a form a team of $11$ members?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

Find the number of ways of selecting $11$ member cricket team from $7$ bats men, $6$ bowlers and $2$ wicket keepers so that the team contains $2$ wicket keepers and atleast $4$ bowlers.

**My attempt:-**
The total number of ways a team can be formed is $15\choose11$.

Out of which,
$13\choose 11$ ways are for the number of ways of having $0$ wicket keepers.
$14\choose 11$ ways counts for having $1$ wicket keeper.

Similarly,
Note that we shouldn't have $2$ or $3$ bowlers which is possible in those $\binom{15}{12}$. So, we have $\binom{11}{11}$ cases where we can have $2$ bowlers and $\binom{12}{12}$ with $3$ bowlers.

So the required number of teams would be,
$$\binom{15}{11}-\binom{14}{11}-\binom{13}{11}-1-\binom{12}{11}$$
Which gives me $910$ but the answer is $560$
I don't see what other combinations I have taken into consideration. A hint is appreciated.

Comment: Since you have $2$ wicket keepers, and $2$ wicket keepers must be in the team you can discard them(as they will contribute a factor of $1$).

Comment: Calculate the cases with 4, 5 and 6 bowlers.

Comment: @bobeyt6, the case of $0$ and $1$ bowlers won't make a team of $11$. They make a team of $9$ and $10$ members respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct count is a simpler approach in this case:  We must choose both wicket keepers, leaving nine members of the team to choose from among the seven bats men and six bowlers.  Of these, at least four must be bowlers, meaning that either four, five, or six bowlers must be selected.  The number of ways of choosing two wicket keepers, exactly $k$ of the six bowlers, and $9 - k$ of the seven bats men is
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{k}\binom{7}{9 - k}$$
Since $4 \leq k \leq 6$, the number of ways to form a cricket team is
$$\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{4}\binom{7}{5} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{5}\binom{7}{4} + \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{6}\binom{7}{3}$$

To do the problem by complementary counting, we would have to exclude all the cases in which we select fewer than two wicket keepers or fewer than four bowlers.  They include selections with

- no wicket keepers, of which there are $\binom{13}{11}$
- exactly one wicket keeper, of which there are $\binom{2}{1}\binom{13}{10}$ since we must choose one of the two wicket keepers and ten of the other $13$ members of the team
- both wicket keepers but only two bowlers, of which there are $\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{7}{7}$
- both wicket keepers but only three bowlers, of which there are $\binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{7}{6}$

Hence, the number of ways the cricket team can be formed is
$$\binom{15}{11} - \binom{13}{11} - \binom{2}{1}\binom{13}{10} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{7}{7} - \binom{2}{2}\binom{6}{3}\binom{7}{6}$$